# Creating a singleton and overriding the alloc class method

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, instantiation, alloc

I've created a singleton class using this code:

```
static MyClass *sharedMyClass = nil;

+ (id)getInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedMyClass;
}
```

my concern is that the users of my class can call the alloc method an create other instantiations of the class. Therefore this would no longer be a singleton Do I need to override the alloc method? If so I suggest overriding it this way:

```
+ (id)alloc
{
  id instance = sharedMyClass;
  if (instance == nil) {
    instance = [super alloc];
  }
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: +(id)alloc
{ @synchronized([MyClass class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedNavTheme == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMyClass = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMyClass;
    }
    return nil;
}

Answer (score 1):

Implement it this way?

```
+(id)alloc
{ @synchronized([MyClass class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMyClass == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMyClass = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMyClass;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _sharedNavTheme?

Comment: why is it under the @synvhronized directive? Is there something that makes it thread unsafe?

Comment: _sharedNavTheme was my singleton i forgot to edit it I corrected now :) and @synchronized make it thread safe not unsafe. It ensures not more than one thread can use the code bound by it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to overwrite the alloc methode.

You can archive this by implementing

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
```

Apple provides a detailed description for this case which you can find here (non ARC description) https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32

Answer (score 0):

You can forbid `alloc` at compile time:

```
+ (instancetype)new NS_UNAVAILABLE;
+ (instancetype)alloc NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

Using `super alloc` in your own implementation:

```
+ (instancetype)getInstance {
  static id sharedMyClass
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedMyClass = [[super alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedMyClass;
}
```

It doesn't protect you from some runtime code, but it's clear enough.